# Balloon in a vacuum

Tags: vacuum

What arrangement will a mixture of low density gas and high density gas take inside a balloon (in a vacuum chamber) in zero gravity? FYI: water boil then freeze's in a vacuum.

which one will stick to the inside surface of the balloon and which one will be in the center?

Comment: In answer to your first question: I don't know why you'd ignore gravity? In answer to your fourth and final question; no. The predominating reason being that, quite intuitively, if you're reaching such temperatures I think you're probably popping the balloon before you split atoms.

Comment: you ignore gravity to form sphere, for example tow liquids with different density will form layers because of gravity.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we can neglect intermolecular bonding (which is very small for most gases) and no chemical interreactions, then in the absence of gravity, the gases will diffuse into each other forming an even mixture (increasing entropy).

Comment: what if we separated the two gases with  balloons by punting the high dense gas balloon inside the low dense gas balloon. will they diffuse  into each other?